# Undefined variable issue in my php project

Tags: php, variables, undefined

[SOLVED]: I've set a SESSION variable that I can use in the whole project ;)

I already took a look at the variable scope argument on the php manual online,but still I couldn't find a solution to my problem :(

In my controller I've got the following:

```
if(isset($_POST["idMappaMod"])){//Modifica mappa
    $oldmap=$this->model->ottieniindirizzo($_POST["idMappaMod"]);
    include'view/modmap.php';
}
```

After the click on the NewMapAddress button,I want to manage that (again in the controller):

```
if (isset($_POST["NewMapAdress"])){
    $result_map_mod=$this->model->modificamappa($oldmap,$this->user->id,$_POST["NewMapAdress"]);
    include'view/modmap.php';
}
```

I get the undefined variable notice on the $oldmap variable. How can I do? Already tried to declare it outside everythin as global. Did not help.

Comment: Are you POST elements named? I.e.: `name="idMappaMod"`

Comment: Yes, they are. Why you ask? The problem is with oldmap in the second "isset". Thx :)

Comment: Sometimes that's a reason for the undefined error.

Comment: `var_dump($oldmap);` and `var_dump($result_map_mod);` see what's going through.

Comment: If you click on the NewMapAddress Button, all let me think that you are creating a new HTTP request on the same controller, right? this way you need to save on sessions the informations you want to retrieve from one request to another. Did you understand?

Answer (score 0):

What about you create a public variable into your class? So you could manage this variable through your instaced class, something like this:

```
<?php
class YourClass {
    public $old;

    public function yourFunction() {
        $this->old = ...
    }
}

$yourClass = new YourClass();
$yourClass->old; // here you have the variable from the instance
?>
```